# Setting Up an image in swift using NSuserdefaults

Tags: xcode, swift, nsuserdefaults

I'm building a swift game and a need to set up some images.
My code works with string or integer:

```
for var i = 0; i < globalCurrentMembers.count; ++i {
    var MembersDefaultName = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    MembersDefaultName.setValue(globalCurrentMembers[i].name, forKey: "globalCurrentMembersName\(i)")
    MembersDefaultName.synchronize()
}
```

But I have an error for an image

```
for var i = 0; i < globalCurrentMembers.count; ++i {
    var MembersDefaultImage = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    MembersDefaultImage.setValue(globalCurrentMembers[i].image, 
                        forKey: "globalCurrentMembersImage\(i)")
    MembersDefaultImage.synchronize()
}
```

`globalCurrentMembers` is an array of `Member` which looks like that:

```
class Member {
   var image = UIImage ()
   var name = String ()
   var progression = Int()
   var round = Int()
   var level = Int()
   var imageProgression = [UIButton]()


   func Init(){
      image = UIImage(named: "default.png")!
      name = "default"
      progression = 0
      round = 0
      level = 0
   }
}
```

So please can you tell me how doing that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIImage does not implement NSCoding protocol, you need to convert UIImage to NSData first.

Change your code to the following:

```
  var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(globalCurrentMembers[i].image)
  var myEncodedImageData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(imageData)
  MembersDefaultImage.setObject(myEncodedImageData, forKey: "globalCurrentMembersImage\(i)")
```

Of course storing image to NSUserDefaults is not the best practice, you should store your image in some file directory.

Comment: Thx for this response but I agree with @Catfish_Man: I can store only the name of the image. But it's works :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't store images in NSUserDefaults. Have you considered storing just the path to the image, or the name of the image, instead? That would be enormously more efficient, and also work.

Comment: It's not my question but you're right it's really a better idea. Thx a lot.